Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade, apport-python3 failing to update
I ran a 24.04 update for all my raspberry pi servers, and 1 of them is failing, in a strange way. I am stuck with what to do, and am hoping someone can unstuck me. Here's the error:
sudo apt autoremove                                                                                                                                          12:36:56
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-apport
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apturl apturl-common gcc-12-base gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gsfonts
  guile-2.2-libs irqbalance libaacs0 libabsl20210324 libaio1 libappstream4 libatk1.0-data libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2
  libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libbluray2 libboost-dev libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0
  libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libboost1.83-dev libbpf0 libcamel-1.2-63 libcbor0.8 libchromaprint1 libclang-cpp14t64 libcodec2-1.0 libcolamd2
  libcupsfilters1 libdav1d5 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdazzle-common libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdns-export1110 libecal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libflac8 libfontembed1
  libfreerdp-client2-2t64 libfreerdp-server2-2t64 libfreerdp2-2t64 libgcab-1.0-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libgme0 libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-common libgupnp-1.2-1 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libilmbase25 libisc-export1105 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libjs-highlight.js liblua5.2-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmessaging-menu0 libmozjs-91-0 libmpdec3 libnautilus-extension1a libnetpbm10
  libnetplan0 libnfs13 libnsl-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-pthread-dev libopenblas0 libopenexr25 libopenmpt0t64 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libpcre3 libperl5.34 libplist3
  libpodofo0.9.7 libpoppler118 libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28 libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5qmlmodels5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 librabbitmq4 libraw20 libre2-10 libre2-9
  librest-0.7-0 libruby3.0 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsnapd-glib1 libsoup-gnome-2.4-1 libspice-server1 libsrt1.4-gnutls
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libsuitesparseconfig5 libswresample3 libtiff5 libtirpc-dev libudfread0 libunistring2 libvncserver1 libvpx7 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwinpr2-2t64 libx264-163
  libxsimd-dev linux-firmware-raspi linux-headers-5.15.0-1055-raspi linux-image-5.15.0-1055-raspi linux-modules-5.15.0-1055-raspi linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1055-raspi
  linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1055 linux-raspi-tools-5.15.0-1055 linux-tools-5.15.0-1055-raspi llvm-14 llvm-14-dev llvm-14-linker-tools llvm-14-runtime llvm-14-tools lua-lpeg lua5.2 lz4
  perl-modules-5.34 python3-backcall python3-beniget python3-cssutils python3-future python3-gast python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-macaroonbakery python3-pickleshare
  python3-ply python3-protobuf python3-pyatspi python3-pymacaroons python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine python3-pythran python3-requests-toolbelt
  python3-rfc3339 python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal ruby3.0 ubuntu-advantage-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-apport
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 185 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/92.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,587 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 358587 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 54, in from_package
    stdout = str(stdout, 'utf-8')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 3: invalid start byte
dpkg: warning: old python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 54, in from_package
    stdout = str(stdout, 'utf-8')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 3: invalid start byte
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 323, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 302, in main
    compile(files, versions,
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 185, in compile
    for fn, versions_to_compile in filter_files(files, e_patterns, versions):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 128, in filter_files
    for fpath in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 71, in filter_public
    for fn in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 54, in from_package
    stdout = str(stdout, 'utf-8')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 3: invalid start byte
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I can't do anything with apt, because this one package is breaking. I have tried sudo apt-get reinstall --force python3-apport with no success. I have tried running the dpkg package manually with dpkg --force-depends -i python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb with no success. I have tried looking for a while for this error online, with no success. It looks like I need to get the old package out of there so I can put the new one in, but it's just not letting me. Please help.
